# C# use where keyword on classes with XmlElementAttribute properties

Tags: c#, generics, xml-serialization, where-clause, type-constraints

This is what I'm looking to do:

```
public class NormalClass
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Example;
}

[XmlRoot]
public class GenericClass<T> where T : HasXmlElementAttribute
{
    [XmlArray]
    public List<T> Variables;
}
```

I thought `where T : IXmlSerializable` *might* work, but it did not.

Is this even possible to do?  If so, what is the proper way?

#### Additional Thoughts/Edit

Is there a way to achieve this same goal? Is there a way to only allow classes that can be xml serialized?

Thanks

Comment: I find that _even if_ classes are adorned with XML attributes they can still be classes that are non-serializable. Thus far the only way I have figured out whether or not a type serializes (_and deserializes_ successfully) is to simply try serializing/deserializing it at runtime. So you can either do that once statically per type or better yet, create unit tests that check for you. Ultimately, I find that if you expose an interface to perform XML serialization for a 3rd party to leverage, the onus is on the 3rd party to ensure they pass XML-serializable types or face exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use generic type constraints to limit the type parameters by what attributes they are decorated with. You can only use generic type constraints to limit type parameters by:

- What base the type parameter inherits
- What interfaces the type parameter implements
- What constructors the type parameter provides
- Whether the type parameter is a value type or a reference type

**Further Reading:**

- [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

### Attributes are not part of the type system.

You cannot constrain a type parameter based on the presence of an attribute.

---

Side note: This justification is not quite valid; constructors aren't part of the type system either, yet `: new()` is a valid constraint.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this same goal? Is there a way to only allow classes that can be xml serialized?